# Remove Namespace references from XML with Regex

Tags: xml, regex

I have a regex that removes xmlns references from XML. It works fine when there are matching tags, but if the the xmlns reference is in a single tag it removes "/" as well.

Here is the regex:

```
"<(.*?) xmlns[:=].*?>", "<$1>"
```

When I use the regex on this line of xml:

```
<ns22:someTagName xmlns:ns22="http://exampledatatypes.com"></ns22:someTagName>
```

I get what I want:

```
<ns22:someTagName></ns22:someTagName>
```

When I use the regex on this line of xml:

```
<ns22:someTagName xmlns:ns22="http://exampledatatypes.com"/>
```

I get this invalid XML:

```
<ns22:someTagName>
```

It removes the reference fine, but it takes the closing "/" with it.

Thanks for the help,
Scott

Comment: Don't use regex for XML. What programming language are you using? Undoubtedly there is a superior XML API that would allow you remove namespaces easily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rather than trying to preserve what you need from the XML it would be better to target what you want to remove.

This expression targets just the namespace itself:

> `\sxmlns[^"]+"[^"]+"`

Unfortunately I don't know LotusScript so I can't give you a code sample of how to use this but what you need to do is something like this psuedocode:

```
result = regex.replace(yourString, '\sxmlns[^"]+"[^"]+"', '')
```

What you will do here is replace all matches with an empty string (effectively removing them). This will work for both a closed and self-closed XML tag and it will also work if the tag doens't have a namespace at all.

**Edit:** Here is a fully-functional Python example:

```
>>> from re import sub
>>> pattern = r'\sxmlns[^"]+"[^"]+"'
>>> closed = r'<ns22:someTagName xmlns:ns22="http://exampledatatypes.com"></ns22:someTagName>'
>>> sub(pattern, '', closed)
'<ns22:someTagName></ns22:someTagName>'
>>> selfclosed = r'<ns22:someTagName xmlns:ns22="http://exampledatatypes.com"/>'
>>> sub(pattern, '', selfclosed)
'<ns22:someTagName/>'
```

Comment: Hmmm. I tried it and it didn't seen to do anything. In LS you need to escape " with another ". Here is what i tried:
ExecuteReplace(sXML, "xmlns[^""]+""[^""]+""", "")

Comment: Hi Andrew, I got it to work, but it leaves whitespace in the tag where the reference is removed. Is there a way to clear the whitespace out? ExecuteReplace(sXML, "xmlns[^""]+""[^""]+""", "")

Comment: @Scott - I changed the expression to this: `\sxmlns[^"]+"[^"]+"` to handle the whitespace issue.

Comment: I added a space in front of xmlns and it fixed it:  ExecuteReplace(sXML, " xmlns[^""]+""[^""]+""", ""). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

[Don't use regex on XML if you have access to an XML parser!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) That being said, I don't know anything about LotusScript's XML parsing capabilities (if it even has them), so if you must use regex, this will get you closer:

```
<([^>]*?)\bxmlns\b[^"']+('|").*?$2(.*?/?>)
```

to be replaced with:

```
<$1$3
```

The most important change here from your original regex is the `/?` toward the end. BTW, I haven't escaped the qoutes or backslashes since I don't know LotusScript syntax for that, and I assume you do.

There will always be XML-valid input that cannot be properly understood by this, due to the [limitations of regex](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2008/10/15/regular-expression-limitations.aspx). However, it should work for most cases. You could double-check manually by searching for the string "xmlns" afterward.

Answer (score 0):

regex `\s*xmlns(:\w+)?="[^"]*"` can remove both implicit / named xmlns.

In Java, `xmlString.replaceFirst("\\s*xmlns(:\\w+)?=\"[^\"]*\"", "")`

https://regexr.com/ is a great tool to use for writing/testing these.